# Continuous disk activity on 18.04 blocks all processes

Tags: disk

At random times but typically 30 minutes since starting 18.04 I experience continuous HDD activity that blocks every other activity including trying to monitor using system monitor and keyboard inputs. Mouse responds but with a lag of around 20-30 seconds and then jerks about a cm every second so it's impossible to switch tasks. Using system monitor in a separate window fails as it's also frozen so never shows the culprit! The only response is to the power off button. After 10-15 minutes of this activity everything clears and anything I've been working on with Firefox has been lost as both open windows and data have been closed. Any suggestions how to continuously log which processes are responsible with a sufficient priority that it can log during the activity?

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5664        2137        1758         429        1768        2838
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

Comment: Take a look at /var/log/messages arounf the time of the problem. Also you could start `top` before the problem starts, maybe it will show which process that uses all resources.

Comment: Sounds like low memory. Please [edit] your question to include the output of `free -m`

Comment: Checked the /var/log/syslog file and building up to the problem time lots of messages identical to this bug with the apparmor package https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/1787600